# Лямбда выражения Java 8 (сортировка String)

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение

```
public static <T> void sort(String ... array, Comparator<T> comparator){
    String buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++) {

            if(comparator.compare(array[i], array[j]) == 1){
                buffer = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = buffer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В качестве компаратора
используйте лямбда-функцию, задающую реализацию методу `compare()` из интерфейса

```
java.util.Comparator.
```

Comment: А зачем вам в этой точке лямбда, простите? Какова ваша цель? Почему нельзя обойтись обыкновенным условием?

Comment: задание такое..

Comment: Не, не может быть. Какое _конкретно_ у вас задание? Потому что в таком виде код не имеет смысла. Лямбда используется для _определения_ функции.

Comment: в качестве компаратора
используйте лямбда-функцию, задающую реализацию методу compare() из интерфейса
java.util.Comparator.

Comment: на этом место был метод compare

Comment: Ну так отлично. А откуда её нужно брать, не сказали? Поинтересуйтесь, будете удивлены.

Comment: Верните метод compare назад, он там был как раз на месте.

Comment: @VladD что нужно брать? я вообще не понимаю как работают лямбда-функции, читал пару статей - ничего не понял для себя.

Comment: Лямбда-функция — это просто один из методов создания объекта. В вашем случае это объект типа java.util.Comparator. Если вам известен код вашего компаратора, то объект не нужен, и лямбда тем самым тоже не нужна. Для вашего случая наверняка компаратор нужно передавать снаружи. Функция, которая использует Comparator, вообще никак не знает, был этот компаратор создан как лямбда, или как обычно через new. Лямбда должна быть снаружи функции, при вызове.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант пузырьковой сортировки с лямбдой - может он вам поможет. Строки сортируются в данном случае сначала по длине,  потом по индексу буквы `e`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class TestCompareStrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"red", "green", "blue"};
        sort((a, b) -> {
            return a.length() > b.length() ? 1 : (a.length() == b.length()) ? 0 : -1;
        }, arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        sort((a, b) -> {
            return a.indexOf('e') > b.indexOf('e') ? 1 : (a.indexOf('e') == b.indexOf('e')) ? 0 : -1;
        }, arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    }

    public static void sort(Comparator<String> comparator, String[] array) {
        String buffer;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = array.length - 2; j >= i; j--) {

                if (comparator.compare(array[j], array[j + 1]) == 1) {
                    buffer = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = buffer;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```